# How to handle React js concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, reactjs, reactjs-flux

What is the better way to handle concurrency inside a flux store, when you have a lot of react js suscribed components to the same flux store ?.

Comment: I have been tempting to use immutable js, but i don't know how to use it in a proper way

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by `concurrency`?  JavaScript is single threaded.  And how many is `a lot`?  What kind of problem are you seeing?

Comment: I think you want to have one parent component listen for the `change` to the store and then pass down to its children, which could be your components. Instead of having each component listen to the `change` event.

Comment: Agree with andykenward here, check out this concept of smart and dumb components here https://github.com/gaearon/redux#components

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can set Boolean attributes in your store, and use them to check if a task is running or finished by dispatching events from your action.

Like a

```js
// set 'loading' in your store, 
// then you can display spinner for exemple
dispatch(ACTION_START)
```

then

```js
// set loading to false and loaded to true, 
// you can also implement an action running count for exemple
dispatch(ACTION_END)
```